# When italicizing, do I have to include 'a,' 'an,' and 'the'?

Tags: writing, mathematics, academic-writing

For example, I want to emphasize the term 'multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem' in the following statements.

> Based on (1), (2), and (3), the multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem for ~~~~~ is finally formulated as follows.

In the above statements, do I have to italicize "multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem" or "the multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem"?

1.

> Based on (1), (2), and (3), the *multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem* for ~~~~~ is finally formulated as follows.

2. 

> Based on (1), (2), and (3), *the multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem* for ~~~~~ is finally formulated as follows.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to include the real example, and don't use "variables" like "ABC" What are the actual words that you have replaced by "ABC" and "~~~~~~" ?  In particular it is not clear why you would italicise "ABC problem".  This is normally to create a contrast with another thing that is unemphasized.

Comment: @JamesK I have revised the questionnaire based on your advice.

Comment: Thanks I think this confirms what I suggest.  Probably no italics at all.  If you need italics for contrast only italicise the particlar parts that are constrastive, eg "the multi-channel non-orthogonal *multiple access* scheduling problem" (constasted with "the 
multi-channel non-orthogonal *single access* scheduling problem")

Comment: In mathematics (which you have tagged), italics may identify terms that are being defined. For example, "Two vectors are _orthogonal_ if their inner product is zero," when the word "orthogonal" has not yet been used and the quoted sentence will be used as the definition of "orthogonal" in the rest of the document. If the quoted passage is your way of defining what the noun phrase "multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem" means, and you consistently use italics for definitions, italicize that phrase, but don't call it emphasis.

Comment: 'the [problem of] multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling [is] formulated as:  (No italics nor emphasis needed, but I'd italicize the name of the formula) XY over Z; Rachet's *right-hand rule*.'

Comment: Considering the answers comprehensively, it was decided to keep italicized for the purpose of defining the term, or write it in the form of the problem of "~~~". As an aside, the APA guide is very useful for me. Thank you for all comments

Comment: The reason for the answers below disagreeing, I think, is that, in the situation where you want to emphasize the term, you probably would italicize the article, but in the situation where you're highlighting a defining mention, you would not italicize the article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, don't use italics for emphasis!  the [APA guide](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/italics-quotations/italics) says:

> In general, avoid using italics for emphasis. Instead, rewrite your sentence to provide emphasis.

You should only use italics if there is a chance of misreading, or if the emphasis changes the meaning of the sentence.

The APA do, however, recommend italics for the first mention of a term, often followed by its definition.

However, if you do use italics, it is completely up to you whether or not to italicise the article, it is a typographic detail that you readers probably won't even notice.

> Based on (1), (2), and (3), the *multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem for ~~~~~* is finally formulated as follows:

If you are emphasising for contrast, then only add italics to the particular element that is contrasted.  If you are contrasting the ABC problem with the XYZ problem then you would emphasise ABC (and you don't need to emphasise "problem")

> Unlike the problems with fertilizers, the *pesticide* problem can be formulated in terms of ...

But if you are contrasting the ABC problem with the ABC solution you emphasise "problem"

> Pesticides have many uses for modern farms, but the pesticide *problem* can be formulated as...

Rr in your example, eg "the multi-channel non-orthogonal *multiple access* scheduling problem" (contrasted with "the
multi-channel non-orthogonal *single access* scheduling problem")

You emphasise the part that you want to contrast.

Comment: I think the problem name is quite a long (connection of nouns). Hence, I thought it would be good for readers to write the whole problem name in italics.

Comment: See the APA style guide.  Don't use italics for this.

Comment: From the question it is not clear that this *is* actually emphasis, rather than the defining instance of a specific term. If it is the definition then this use of italics is conventional, including in APA, and whether the article is to be included or not may not be completely up to the author.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Based on your answer, when I pondered more, the expression I was trying to make seems to be the introduction of terms, not emphasis. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesK, just out of curiosity why APA style? The tag is "mathematics" so a different style may be more appropriate.

Comment: No special reason, just a well known and respected style guide, and the first one that came to mind.

Comment: @JamesK, thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, in scholarly papers, when a new concept is defined or introduced, the article is never italicized, and the rest of the noun phrase is usually italicized.

Here are several examples from the book *Category Theory* by Steve Awodey. In all cases, the italics are quoted exactly as they appear in the original text.

> A *category* consists of the following data: […]
>
> A *preorder* is a set *P* equipped with a binary relation […]
>
> Thus, *A*∗
> is a monoid – called the *free monoid* on
> the set *A*.

Your sentence seems like it introduces a new concept, so it should use italics in exactly the same way:

> Based on (1), (2), and (3), the *multi-channel non-orthogonal multiple access scheduling problem* for ~~~~~ is finally formulated as follows.

I don't think I've ever seen the article italicized in these sorts of sentences. If I came across a sentence like this where the article is italicized, I'd find it a little strange, but probably not strange enough to call it an error.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a rule which would advise against any of the two options, but I would definitely italicize *THE* as well, because it determines your "ABC problem", "the ABC problem" is the complete unit. Even "esthetically" it looks better than separating "the" from the phrase it determines.

Answer (score 2):

You want to stress [a noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) (*the ABC problem*), and [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) (*the*) is a constituent part of it.

Comment: Ironically, I wouldn't include the articles *a* or *an* in both of those links.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether "the" is part of the actual phrase or just a helper word. In your example, I believe it is just a helper word and would not ordinarily be italicized.